MongoDB filter on same object in array
I have object with column chars with such data:
{
  "chars": [
    {
      "count": 1,
      "color": "red"
    },
    {
      "count": 2,
      "color": "green"
    },
    {
      "count": 3,
      "color": "blue"
    }
  ]
}

I want to exclude records with chars like
{"count": 2, "color": "blue"}

I filter by (demo1)
{
    "$or": [
        {
            "chars.count": {
                "$ne": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "chars.color": {
                "$ne": "blue"
            }
        }
    ]
}

or (demo2)
{
    "chars.count": {
        "$ne": 2
    },
    "chars.color": {
        "$ne": "blue"
    }
}

I want to receive object, but receive empty set.
I use MongoDB 6.0.6

Like this demo?

Yes, but now not filters 3 and blue

Your question is unclear. You want the returned document with filtered chars in the projection? Should be filter 2 not 3 according to your question?

I want to receive whole object with array chars with all objects in it, because I haven't {"count": 2, "color": "blue"}

I think what you're looking for is to use the $elemMatch query operator to match documents that have an array element containing { count: 2, color: "blue" } and just negate the results by using $not. This will return all documents that didn't match, which I think is what you're aiming for:
db.collection.find({
  chars: {
    $not: {
      $elemMatch: {
        count: 2,
        color: "blue"
      }
    }
  }
})

See HERE for a working example.

Your query should be like this
"$or": [
    { "chars.count": { "$ne": 2 } },
    { "chars.color": { "$ne": "blue" } }
  ]

